# Display each item from an NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {

  NSString *j = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", i];

  NSArray *fields = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       @"name", nil];
  //@"title",@"mobile",@"email",@"website"
      [requestExecute setMethod:@"execute" withObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                      @"testdb", userid, @"admin", @"res.partner.contact", @"read", j, fields, nil]];
  NSDictionary *records = [self executeXMLRPCRequest:requestExecute];

  NSLog(@"\nKey : %@ value : \n", records);
}
```

The output looks like

```
2011-04-09 12:34:32.431 Erp[1571:207] (  
        {  
        email = "benoit@yahoo.com";  
        id = 1;  
        mobile = 12345;  
        name = Mortier;  
        title = "Ms.";  
        website = "www.benoit.com";  
    }  
)  
2011-04-09 12:34:32.515 Erp[1571:207] (  
        {  
        email = "laurent@hotmail.com";  
        id = 2;  
        mobile = 23455;  
        name = Jacot;  
        title = "M.";  
        website = "www.laurent.com";  
    }  
)  
2011-04-09 12:34:32.599 Erp[1571:207] (  
        {  
        email = "thomas@yahoo.com";  
        id = 3;  
        mobile = 34567;  
        name = Passot;  
        title = "M.";  
        website = "www.thomas.com";  
    }  
)  
2011-04-09 12:34:32.683 Erp[1571:207] (  
        {  
        email = "etienne@yahoo.com";  
        id = 4;  
        mobile = 45678;  
        name = Lacarte;  
        title = Mss;  
        website = "www.etienne.com";  
    }  
)  
2011-04-09 12:34:32.767 Erp[1571:207] (  
        {  
        email = "chow@gmail.com";  
        id = 5;  
        mobile = 56789;  
        name = Tang;  
        title = Mss;  
        website = "www.chow.com";  
    }  
)  
2011-04-09 12:34:32.851 Erp[1571:207] (  
        {  
        email = "hudson@gmail.com";  
        id = 6;  
        mobile = 1237091;  
        name = Wong;  
        title = "M.";  
        website = "www.hudson.com";  
    }  
)
```

This prints each record one by one. Now I'd like to get each field in this record one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to cycle each key with this one:

```
for(NSString *key in records) {
   //do something with key or [records objectForKey:key];
}
```